# Capistrano failed with bundle exit status 127

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy my project to my DigitalOcean droplet but I'm getting an error.

```
DEBUG [9bbcec2c] Command: cd /home/deploy/movieseat/releases/20150902152631 && /usr/bin/env bundle install --path /home/deploy/movieseat/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
DEBUG [9bbcec2c]    /usr/bin/env: 
DEBUG [9bbcec2c]    bundle
DEBUG [9bbcec2c]    : No such file or directory
DEBUG [9bbcec2c]    
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@178.62.204.53: bundle exit status: 127
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: /usr/bin/env: bundle: No such file or directory

SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 127
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: /usr/bin/env: bundle: No such file or directory

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@178.62.204.53: bundle exit status: 127
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: /usr/bin/env: bundle: No such file or directory
```

I've done some searching and saw that the most common fix was to install Bundler on the server, but I've done that. On my server I do,

```
bundler -v
Bundler version 1.10.6
```

So I'm wondering what the error could be now.

Comment: Hey Peter, did you manage to fix/workaround this? I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Tbh I dumped my whole DigitalOcean droplet and started from scratch.

Comment: and I guess you went with single user installation of rvm which avoided the whole problem?

Comment: I followed this guide for installation etc, https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04

Comment: After adding gem `capistrano-rvm` in `Gemfile`, run bundle, then add require `capistrano/rvm` in Capfile